# Is there an R function like ggplot or plot to show all my time series curve in the same graphs by id and with differents colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to plot the mean temperature by age (in days) and by id on the same graph.

First of all i use plot functions by doing this:

```
age_Temperature=tapply(merge_reprise$Temperature,list(merge_reprise$Id,merge_reprise$Age),mean)  

plot(age_Temperature[1,1:ncol(age_Temperature)],type='l',pch=20,xlab="âge",ylab = "Temperature",col="red")

for (ligne in 2:nrows(age_Temperature)) {
    lines(age_Temperature[ligne,1:ncol(age_Temperature)],col=c("green","blue","yellow","antiquewhite"))
          ligne=ligne+1
}
```

But i can't see all the curves on the graphs, and the color doesn't change.

I try this one which seems to be better but i can't see the curves. I can just see the vertical lines and one curve.

```
aql <- melt(age_Temperature, id.vars = "Id")
aql=aql[order(aql$Id),]
p<- ggplot(aql,na.rm = TRUE, aes(x=variable, y=value,na.rm = TRUE, color=Id,group=1)) + 
  geom_line()+
  labs(title="Distribution de la temperature en fonction de l'age ", 
       y="Temperature")
print(p)
```

I expect the output to be like this: All curves on the same graphs,by differents id, with differents colors.

I attach the screenshot of my data, what i found with the first code and what i have found with the second code.

the first picture is for the data base, the second is for the first code and the third is for the second code. thanks

This is the dput of my dataset:

```
structure(list(Id = c("110f", "110f", "110f", "110f", "110f", 
                                  "110f", "110f", "110f", "110f", "110f", "3270", "3270", "3270", 
                                  "3270", "3270", "3270", "3270", "3270", "3270", "354f", "354f", 
                                  "354f", "354f", "354f", "354f", "354f", "354f", "354f", "354f"
), variable = c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 3, 6, 9, 
                12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28), 
value = c(38.730612244898, 38.9367346938776, 39.019387755102, 
          39.2153583617747, 38.9600682593857, 38.9419795221843, 39, 
          38.8737201365188, 38.5609756097561, 38.8212328767123, NA, 
          39.5494845360825, 39.5896907216495, 39.9, 39.4855670103093, 
          39.3525773195876, 39.3855670103093, 39.3632653061225, 39.3575862068965, 
          NA, 39.4225235849057, 39.6268041237113, 39.5020618556701, 
          39.5895833333333, 39.5666666666667, 39.4302083333333, 39.3822916666667, 
          39.6345360824742, 39.4631944444444)), row.names = c(NA, -29L
          ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is this changing something : `aql %>% na.omit() %>% ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = factor(Id))) + geom_line()`? And it would be nice to have a minimum sample of your data.

Comment: aql %>% na.omit() %>% ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = factor(Id),group=1)) + geom_line(). When i use this, it change just for one line. I am looking for a way to send a minimum of my data.

Comment: but you added again group = 1 in your example, you could try without? check the answer below, it produces what you need for a exemple dataset

Comment: i try it first and i got this error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: I can only try to guess like this. With a sample I can maybe solve it. If you wan to send a minimal example use : `dput(yourdata %>% select(col1, col2) %>% filter(Id %in% c("id1", "id2")))`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. It is ok for few data.Because when i use this command aql %>% na.omit() %>% ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = factor(Id))) + geom_line()  with few data it works perfectly so i will manage my data. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using a build-in dataset to show you :

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y=qsec, colour = factor(gear))) +geom_line()
```

You problem may be related to the type of `Id` you need to specify it as a factor to make a coloured line by `Id`